# jQuery - Prevent further code execution until after html has been displayed

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jquery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) with the flash save method. I want set a message after the user clicks save so they know it's saving. My code is this:

```
$('#savepicmessage').html("Saving picture, please wait");
webcam.capture();
webcam.save('/savephoto.php');
```

The problem is that the "Saving picture" message only gets displayed after the picture is saved. Is there a way to prevent execution of the code following the .html("Saving picture, please wait") call, so that it is not executed until the message has been displayed?

I can achieve it with a setTimeout and have the capture and save in the function called from there, however this is not reliable enough.

I looked at .when and deferred.then but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I must admit to total mystification on this one. .html() is not an animation call and should not be kicked off by a timer. The single thread that goes through this code should completely finish the change to the DOM before it calls the two functions. Is this problem consistent across multiple browsers? Also, if you use Firebug or its equivalent to set a breakpoint at the webcam.capture() does the HTML appear updated at that point?

Comment: It happens in firefox, iron and IE (and maybe others, that's all I tried). If I set a breakpoint in firebug, then the HTML appears updated before the script is stopped by the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I use promises and stuff like $.when() to coordinate asynchronous things like AJAX calls or animation. But the fact that this is acting almost like it's asynchronous is amazing to me.

However, I have a suggestion. Can you loop on $('#savepicmessage').html() after the first call to set it and test what comes back? Perhaps once the returned value matches what you tried to set it to, then you could fall through to the webcam functions and your message will be visible to the user prior to invoking the webcam.

Comment: It's not the ideal solution but I think it's the best workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of your plugin, you would structure the loading of your plug-in something like this:

```
 $("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function() {

         $('#savepicmessage').html("Saving picture, please wait");

    },
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
 });
```

Haven't used this plug-in before, so not sure if you would do this `onSave`, `onTick`, `onCapture` or `onLoad`, but if you show your initialization code, would be more helpful.

Comment: I am not using the callback method, I am using the save method, so it is not structured like this. The question is not specific to the webcam plugin, it's a more generic jquery question about how to stop the next thing from happening until the .html has done it's work.

Comment: I don't see a purpose for `.html()` having a callback since it happens so quick.  The next best thing if not with the plug-in is using `setTimeout()`